# SonarQube installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, mysql

I have followed all the steps listed here:
http://mamikon.net/blog/installing-sonarqube-ubuntu/

However,
in my /opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties , these 2 lines are missing:
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery=select 1

so I inserted it and followed other procedure also.
SonarQube service also started but I was not able to access the web page

Answer (score 1):

Those lines belonged to an older version of SonarQube. If you are using SonarQube 5.x, there is no need to set those lines. Check the updated post on http://mamikon.net/blog/installing-sonarqube-ubuntu/